# Why is this code for making a file from user input using the Scanner class not working?

Tags: java

My code is used to create a file inside a folder of a directory, with the file containing a heading at the top based on what the user inputs.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.io.*;

public class setup {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner userin = new Scanner(System.in);
        int hwnum;
        String hwsummary;
        int period;
        String name;
        System.out.println("Enter name: ");
        name = userin.next();
        System.out.println("Enter APCS period: ");
        period = userin.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter HW number: ");
        hwnum = userin.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter HW summary: ");
        hwsummary = userin.next();
        System.out.println("Enter file name: ");
        String hwname = userin.next();
        hwname = hwname + ".java";
        new File("/hw" + hwnum).mkdirs();
        new File("/hw" + hwnum +"/" + hwname);
        String filename;
        filename = "\\hw" + hwnum + "\\" + hwname;
        System.out.println("/*");
        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println("APCS1 " + "pd" + period);
        System.out.println("HW" + hwnum + " -- " + hwsummary);
        System.out.println(getdate());
        System.out.println("*/");
    }
    public static String getdate() {
       DateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
       Date date = new Date();
       String todaydate;
       todaydate = dateformat.format(date);
       return todaydate;
    }
}
```

The end result of the code, if give by the user should be a java file in a directory named "/hwxx" and should have a heading similar to:

```
/*
Name
APCS1 pdx
HW# - HWSUMMARY
DATE
*/
```

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/)

Comment: You might want to provide the actual output too; a running example is great; but still sometimes people don't want to copy/paste, compile/run your input .. but well, for starters: in order to write to a file; well, you should have instructions that write to the file, shouldn't you. There are none. Creating a file doesnt magically push content into the file ...

Comment: Ah sorry for the misconception. Originally I used write from java.io to write to a file, but the question I have was it kept returning an error for FileNotFoundException, and then an exception regarding the format of the text, it would write with, which was UTF-8. After creating catch exceptions for both of those, it kept returning ambiguous errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.out.println()` can't be used to write to a file, only to print text to the standard output stream. A FileWriter and BufferedWriter can be used instead to write to a file. Try replacing the last part of your main method with this:

```
try {
    FileWriter outputStream = new FileWriter(filename);
    try (BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(outputStream)) {
        out.write("/*");
        out.newLine();
        out.write(name);
        out.newLine();
        out.write("APCS1 pd" + period);
        out.newLine();
        out.write("HW" + hwnum + " -- " + hwsummary);
        out.newLine();
        out.write(getdate());
        out.newLine();
        out.write("*/");
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    // some sort of error message here
    // this block will only be run if the program is unable to create or write to the specified file
}
```

Note that the `write()` method is the file-writing equivalent to `print()` rather than `println()`, so it's necessary to include the `newline()` method between each line of text to avoid having it all be written to the same line of text. However, a shorter and less tedious alternative is to add the string `"\n"` (newline) to the end of each line written to the file, like this:

```
out.write("/*\n");
out.write(name + "\n");
//etc.
```

If you choose to do it this way and it ends up writing all the text to a single line anyway (a common problem if you're running Windows), use `"\r\n"` instead of just `"\n"`.

Comment: My file did orginally have write, but it ended up not working due to various errors as I commented above. This was the result of me trying to debug, but it seems you have solved one problem. However, when the file asks for name and I input a String, it returns 

"Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException"

Comment: I tested the main method, and it works just fine. What are you entering as the input?

Comment: I run the java file, and when it prompts for name i enter "First Last", without quotations

Comment: That's because you're using `next()` instead of `nextLine()` to read the name. That only reads the first word entered, so it assigns "First" to `name` and then tries to read the next integer to assign to `period`, which results in an exception because "Last" is not an integer. You'll need to use `nextLine()` whenever you want the Scanner to read a line of text that can contain multiple words.

Comment: That was it. Thanks so much!